# glance as a verb

Tags: word-choice, american-english, word-usage

In today's English, Is it common to use the verb "to glance" vs. to take/have a glance?

Is it natural to say "I glanced it" or in everyday speech, one might only say "I took/had a glance on it"?

Comment: Check a dictionary: you will find that *glance*, verb, is intransitive in almost all its uses; transitive uses are even rarer today than in the past. And the noun is a derivative of the verb.

Comment: _Glance_ is normally intransitive, like _look_. Both verbs transitivize by adding _at_; i.e, _glance at_ and _look at_ are both transitive verbs. As a noun, _a glance_ means 'only a fast impression', and both _glance_ and _impression_ take _of_ to refer to the source of the impression: _I got a glance/a glimpse/an impression of ..._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*glance* is usually intransitive, that is, it doesn't take an object.  Thus, "I glanced it" is gramatically incorrect.

*glance* is followed usually by *at*, e.g., I glanced at the book but didn't read it.  *to glance at* is the most commonly used version of the verb.

It is also possible to say, "He glanced over the offerings on the buffet table" and "he glanced over at the woman at the end of the row", but this also uses *at*.  Also "He glanced about to identify possible threats."

You can also "glance around the room" or "glance behind yourself" or "glance behind the barn."

"Had a glance on" is totally unidiomatic.  But you could say "I had a glance at the paintings while I was in the gallery."

[See MW for further information](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glance).

Comment: I like this explanation. It's very clear and directly to the point of the poster's question. +1.

Comment: Here's [a link](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=yfHoCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT219&dq=%22glanced+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy_4uq5__UAhWCfbwKHXsFBm4Q6AEIRDAF#v=onepage&q=%22glanced%20it%22&f=false) to an example of "glanced it over". It uses the words "glanced" and "it" together as the OP does, but is really "glanced over", as your example has it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to an object, and want to use glance, you ought to include the preposition "at".  You have not "glanced it" or "glanced on it", rather you "glanced **at** it".  So since that isn't grammatically correct, it would not be common, and would sound unnatural.  It's possible that you are thinking of "glimpse".

> Glimpse - A momentary or partial view (OED)

You can say "I glimpsed it".

Just a side note, but a similar, less formal (and more fun sounding) phrase is "gander".

> Gander - [informal] a look or glance. (OED)

If you have glanced at something, you could say you "took a gander at it"

Comment: very nice, but that doesn't answer the question

Comment: @DavidHaim I thought that his second sentence answered the question.

Comment: Third sentence was added for additional clarification.  Remember, users may not be native English speakers, so it's best to make things as clear as possible to accommodate them.

Comment: Enhh...not so sure. I think they might be interchangeable as in "got a _glance/glimpse_" , but for me, as verbs, "glance" and "glimpse" are as different as "look" and "see". IMO the first in both cases expresses intention, and the second happenstance.